# How to have the working dir of a repo in another dir than the .git folder?

Tags: git

I have a repo in dir `~/myRepo/`. Because I want to use this repo across multiple machines, I want to have the `.git` folder in my dir `~/Dropbox/`.

I know, that there was some ability to create a file in `~/myRepo`, which contains a path to the git-folder `~/Dropbox/myRepo.git`, but I forgot which and cannot find the information in the man-pages.

Please don't tell me to simply `ln -s` the folder, I tried this and considered it impracticable.

Comment: Why not just have a bare repository in your Dropbox and push/pull to it from each machine?

Comment: @Abizern: I also thought about this, but I think there's too much overhead.

Comment: I can understand that, but there are advantages. You won't have to worry about the the relative states of your repo and your working directory. It will also be a backup repository so that if you mess up one of your local copies you can just delete it and clone a fresh copy from a good repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the “gitfile” functionality. It is briefly mentioned in [*gitrepository-layout(5)*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrepository-layout.html):

> … (… It is also possible to have a working tree where .git is a plain ASCII file containing `gitdir: <path>`, i.e. the path to the real git repository).

You do not say why symlinks will not work for you but the only advantage this has is that it will work in environments that do not support symlinks. It is effectively an application-level symlink (much like Git’s symbolic refs).

Make `~/myRepo/.git` a normal file with the following text:

```
gitdir: ../Dropbox/myRepo.git
```

*Note*: This setup will use a repository that is probably marked as bare (`~/Dropbox/myRepo.git`) in a non-bare fashion for operations done under `~/myRepo`. You may run into problems.

Comment: The reason is, that I want to have this repository available under a Windows machine too, and as I'm not really familiar with Windows shell, I don't know how to set up a symlink there.

Answer (score 0):

There's the environment variable `GIT_DIR` that can point at a `.git` directory, but you would need to have that set correctly when working in the specific folder.

Comment: AFAIK, there is a file you can add, but I really forgot it's name.